# Mongodb how to change Replica set server from recovering to secondary

Tags: mongodb, replication

I removed the secondary server from the replica set and rescheduled a MongoDB container to a new host. But the newly added server still showing in Recovering state.
Since it is a production environment, How do I change to secondary without affecting the process?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, this will happen automatically.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/#replstate.RECOVERING

> A member transitions from RECOVERING to SECONDARY after replicating
>   enough data to guarantee a consistent view of the data for client
>   reads. The only difference between RECOVERING and SECONDARY states is
>   that RECOVERING prohibits client reads and SECONDARY permits them.
>   SECONDARY state does not guarantee anything about the staleness of the
>   data with respect to the primary.

Comment: Thanks, but it is recovering mode for past 24 hours. Is that ok?

Comment: It doesn't sound ok. Maybe you can use tcpdump to check if data is flowing? How big is the DB? I've never done this, but there is an approach called "to tail the oplog", there you would see the changes in realtime. I don't know if you can or have to do it on the secondary though.